# working with Google Cloud Storage without gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have developed a Software in which is configured directories to save files. I run it on Linux. These directories are informed by config file.

I would like to use compute engine nodes because I need to increase its performance. Therefore, I would like to use Google Storage to save these files into a save repository.

In [1] is showed mounting a bucket as file system. I tried it, but no success. I receive authentication error.

Can anyone help me to get success in order to access my bucket by compute engine nodes ?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets

Best regards,

Comment: Did you run gcloud init on your new instance?

Comment: Create a service account that has read/write access to GCS, then launch an instance that uses that service account. Test that it works by SSHing to the instance and using gsutil.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you did not start your GCE instance with a service account.

According to the docs you linked, you need to [configure a service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using) or run `gcloud auth login` to configure your credentials for accessing cloud storage.

If you are trying to set up `gcsfuse` without running on GCE you will need to use the `gcloud auth login` approach.